# Continuous Python script and restart if ended

Tags: python, cron, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am making a script that reads the output from a 433 MHz receiver over i2c on Arduino to an Raspberry Pi. I have tried to run start it from rc.local, but it seems like after a couple of days the script ends/stops/breaks/halts/is killed (?).

I have tried to run the following script from cron to determine if the runs or not and start the Python script if it has stopped. But it seems to not detect a running script and starts a new script every time it runs and so finally crashing the system.

```
#!/bin/bash
until <path to Python script>; do
    sleep 1
done

exit(0)
```

I have also tried to replace the always true while statement with a statement that lets the script run for a minute and restart the script with cron each minute, but that also results in that the script does not end and a new process is started.

Do anyone have any idea of how I either can make the script stable or able to restart. I.e. Always running all time until infinity! :-)

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Run in correct folder
import os
os.system("<path to script-folder>")

import sys

import MySQLdb as mdb

from smbus import SMBus
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import datetime
import time

addr = 0x10
intPin = 4

bus = SMBus(1)

def readData():

    val = bus.read_byte(addr)
    raw = val << 24

    val = bus.read_byte(addr)
    raw = raw | (val << 16)

    val = bus.read_byte(addr)
    raw = raw | (val << 8)

    val = bus.read_byte(addr)
    raw = raw | val

    # Tidstämpel
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    try:
        con = mdb.connect('<server>', '<User>', '<password>', '<DB>')
        con.autocommit(True)

        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO <DB statement>") # Data is stored as integers

    except mdb.Error, e:
        errorLog = open('<path to log>', 'a')
        errorlog.write("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1]) + "\n")
        errorlog.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:  
        if con: 
            cur.close()  
            con.close()

while True:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(intPin,GPIO.IN)

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(intPin, GPIO.RISING)
    readData()
```

Comment: You seem confused about the reason why your script stops after a few days. Why aren't you investigating this? Seems like the better solution here would be to fix the script so it doesn't crash, not to restart it every time it crashes.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, wth logging etc. But I didn't get any results. Any idea?

Comment: Any number of errors could be causing this code to crash. You have all of the bus.read_byte and attempts at manipulating that data that could have an error.  Consider using at least a try / except block around readData and logging any exceptions.  Debugging this code and making it run reliably is the first thing to do.  Then use something like supervisord that will automatically restart failing code (unless it fails on startup continuously)

Answer (score 1):

use linux screen to run the python script it will always run in backend until you stop the script.

http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). It's small and will ensure your code runs...forever.